# exctracting a list of simple shapes from an image-like data grid

Tags: c, char, struct

For a program I'm required to fill a bunch of variables relating to a grid. On the grid different `char`s represent different cars. Each car can be represented by 2 or 3 `char`s in a line (either vertical or horizontal).

```
/* Structure to hold information about a car */
typedef struct
{
    /* The location of the front of the car.  As all cars are assumed
       to be facing either north or west, this location represents
       the northwest segment of the car */
    LOCATION front;
    /* The orientation of the car */
    ORIENTATION orientation;
    /* The length of the car */
    int length;
} CARINFO;
```

I want to go through a for loop cycling through all the different cars (type `CARINFO`) and fill the variables such as length and front. I have all the logic for this for example:

```
if ((carpark.grid[i + 1][j] == car && carpark.grid[i - 1][j] == car) || // (left and right) OR
    (carpark.grid[i][j + 1] == car && carpark.grid[i][j - 1] == car)) //    (up and down)
    CAR.length = 3;
```

I have used `car` as a `char` and `CAR` as a `CARINFO`.

If I had `struct CARINFO a`; how would I make `car = a` and do the same for all the other cars?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  What do you mean by "getting a char from a struct"?  What is the type of `car`?  What is the type of `carpark.grid`?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing this but trying to get the same effect.
 if(CAR = CAR_a) car = 'a';
 if(CAR = CAR_b) car = 'b';
 if(CAR = CAR_c) car = 'c';
 if(CAR = CAR_d) car = 'd';

car is type char. 

typedef struct
{
 /* Rectangular grid of characters representing the position of
    all cars in the game.  Each car appears precisely once in
    the carpark */
 char grid[MAXCARPARKSIZE][MAXCARPARKSIZE];
 /* The number of rows used in carpark */
 int nRows;
 /* The number of columns used in carpark */
 int nCols;
 /* The location of the exit */
 LOCATION exit;
} CARPARK;

Comment: Your last line kind of doesn't make sense. what do you mean by `car = a`? If you want to have a list of cars, it should be `CARINFO list[100]` for example (100 is an example) or `CARINFO *list = malloc(count*sizeof(*list));` then, if you found the `n`th car, you fill it in `CAR` and then copy it in the list: `list[n] = CAR; ++n;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to provide you with code, but an idea. What you should do is, well first basically a loop on the rows, inside it a loop on the columns:

```
for (i = 0; i < grid_row_size; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < grid_col_size; ++j)
```

Then you should detect a car (like the code you provided, but make sure you take care of boundaries. So for example when `i==0` you shouldn't check `grid[i-1][j]`.

Then, whenever you found a car, you set it's length, position and orientation they way you like and add it to a list (array) of CARINFO.

Finally, to make sure you don't find a car twice, whenever you find a car on the grid, you go over it and mark it as `car_already_seen`.

Comment: @pseudoabdul did you get your answer to this question?